# HTTPURLConnection result in struts2

Tags: java, struts2

I want to return `HttpURLConnection` result as a **Struts 2** result type.

Can you suggest how to do?

Actually I want to fetch JSP Page from other server using `HttpURLConnection`, then that page need to display.

How to do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Our requirement is submitting the form data to other domain.So instead of giving the remote url in form action,i just using my struts2 action url and submitting the form data,,In that action class i am calling httpurlconnection to post the data to other domain and receiving the response(page).That response i need to use in result type.

Comment: Looks like XY problem, none of the result type for httpurlconnection ever existed but you add it as a parameter to the custom result type. Fetching jsp and executing its result is different and requires dispatcher result. What you actually doing is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you simply want to pass-through the already rendered content from the remote server when your Struts2 action returns.

Since the JSP has already been rendered, all you need to do is to set your Struts2 action result type to use `stream` and simply return the content of the rendered JSP you obtained from your `HTTPUrlConnection` appropriately.

```
<action name="yourAction" class="com.yourcompany.YourAction">
  <result type="stream">
    <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
    <param name="inputName">jspResponse</param>
  </result>
</action>
```

Then your action simply needs to expose your `InputStream` with a getter `getJspResponse()` since we've specified the property to get as `jspResponse`.